# Unable to declare multiline string in JS File with ES6 format

Tags: karate

I am trying to declare multiline string variable in a JS file. However it seems that Karate won't let me to declare the string in ES6 format such as:

```
var stringQuery =
`
multiline
string
`
```

The execution will be failed complaining it does not match requirement. Is it currently impossible to do this in Karate? Or is there any workaround to achieve such feat?
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ES6 will be supported when we move to [Graal](https://github.com/intuit/karate/projects/3#card-22529293), but not right now, sorry.

We recommend you don't do "too much" in JS and stick to the basics in a feature file. FWIW, you can declare a multi line string in a feature file using the `text` syntax as follows:

```
# csv conversion
* text foo =
    """
    name,type
    Billie,LOL
    Bob,Wild
    """
* csv bar = foo
* match bar == [{ name: 'Billie', type: 'LOL' }, { name: 'Bob', type: 'Wild' }]
```

And you should be able to pass it into a JS chunk (or file).

EDIT: you can also read a text file any time in Karate, even from within JS:

Karate:

```
* def foo = read('foo.txt')
```

JS:

```
var foo = read('foo.txt);
```